# destruction es6 default value in react's props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`<ComponentB from="3/1/2016" to="12/1/2016" />`

and in componentB's constructor I can do

`const { from, to } = this.props` but my from to value is optional. I can't do

`this.state = { from, to }` if they are or null. Any way to set default value for destruction?

I can do `if(from && to) {}` but just curious what's the best way to handle optional props in react.

Answer (score 9):

You can use any of these two ways:

**1.** Assign the default values to variable during the destructuring, like this:

```
const { from = 'abc', to ='abc' } = this.props;
```

If `this.props` doesn't contains any key it will take the default value 'abc'.

**2.** Use `defaultProps` to assign the default values to props variable, like this:

```
ComponentName.defaultProps = {
    from: 'abc',
    to: 'abc'
};
```

All the `props` passed from parent component will be assigned these default values.

Check this example:

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

var {a=5, b=5, d=5} = obj;

console.log(a, b, d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use default props to set default values to 'to' and 'from' variables.

```js
Component.defaultProps = {
 from: "28/12/1992",
 to: "28/12/1992"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider Using typechecking and  defaultProps to set up the defaults for the props you are expecting see the docs here.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

In your case you could define.

```
//declare default Props expected by app
ComponentB.propTypes =  {
 from: PropTypes.string,
 to: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

//set our default values
ComponentB.defaultProps = {
 to:"0/0/0"
 from:"0/0/0" 
};
```

Consider here I used string and I declared that the `to` prop is required but the from doesn't have the isRequired flag. NB I used string here but there is numerous other types you can use.